# Overcounting foliations in quantum cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, path-integral, quantum-gravity

Assume that we have states of 3-space with an intrinsic metric $h^{ij}$, and that we have already factored out equivalent 3-metrics.

In quantum cosmology, one might evolve a state with some intrinsic metric to another, summing over all the ways of doing this.

But consider just flat Minkowski space, since there are many ways to foliate this, one could find many different paths through the space of intrinsic metrics to get from one state to another.

It would thus seems a naiive path integral over intrinic metrics would overcount considerably!

But on the other hand, does this matter? If the overcounting is consistent for different spaces then it would just contribute an overall factor one could divide out.

Basically what I'm saying is taking a 3-metric $h^{ij}(t)$ depending on the foliation variable $t$, is this likely to lead to overcounting of the spaces? Andwhat happened to the laspe function?

**Edit:**
Oh, I see that basically you are fixing the lapse function and shift vector so that defines a unique foliation. So this guage fixes it and you are left with the 3-metric to sum over.

Comment: What is "quantum cosmology" here, exactly? What framework are you using to "evolve metrics"? You talk about a path integral but haven't told us the action or anything else specific about the theory under consideration here. Please be mindful that other users only have the context that you give in the question, and there's not enough here (at least for me) to tell what you're actually trying to do or what the question is on a technical level.

Comment: Euclidean Quantum Gravity. Or any other method using a path integral over metrics.